# Github Page Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: html, github-pages

I've looked around the forums but unfortunately couldn't find the answers I was looking for - basically I have a HTML page that renders perfectly locally in chrome but when uploaded onto GitHub it renders incorrectly (the lower subscription form and social icons in the pop out menu)
I've ran it through some cross-browser compatibility tools and it seems to render correctly on ca 70% of browsers. Im really not sure what the cause is, would love some help on this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">

    <title>WEAVE.</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#theMenu">
  
 <!-- Menu -->
 <nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
  <div class="menu-wrap">
   <h1 class="logo"><a><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/logo-text.png" alt="WEAVE."></a></h1>
   <i class="fa fa-times menu-close"></i>
   <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
   <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
   <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Menu button -->
  <div id="menuToggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
 </nav>

 <section id="home" ></section>
 <div id="headerwrap">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <h1><a><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="WEAVE."></a></h1>
    </div>
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
 </div><!--/headerwrap-->
 
 <section id="about"></section>
 <div id="aboutwrap">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 name">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/pic.png" alt="WEAVE.">
     <p>WHATS IT ABOUT?</p>
     <div class="name-label"></div>
    </div><!--/col-lg-4-->
    <div class="col-lg-8 name-desc">
     <h2>THE BEST MOMENTS<br/>ARE THE ONES WE FIND<br/>WHILE LOOKING FOR SOMETHING ELSE</h2>
     <div class="name-zig"></div>
     
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Being loved, sad, determined and hopeful are just a few of the thousands of emotions that we all commonly share between us. Describing these important moments with words alone doesn’t usually live up to how we truly feel. Creating a small post that captures our thoughts, and connects it with its abstract surroundings; allows us to illustrate the real value and importance that words alone sadly can’t.</p>
      <p>Weave is all about reflecting on special moments and exploring how they mesh and interact with the world.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>It’s not designed to be searched or filed away, but to be randomly explored like stumbling upon an obscure and insightful message with a friend.</p>
      <p>Spending some time to explore through Weave gives us a chance to experience and feel that we normally forget. Weave leads us to states of mind, feelings and those little hidden inward passages that we’d otherwise rarely visit.</p>
      <p>Because the best moments are always the ones we stumble upon while looking for something else.</p>
     </div>
     
    </div><!--/col-lg-8-->
  
   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /aboutwrap -->
 
 <!--ABOUT SEPARATOR-->
 
 <section id="contact"></section>
 <!--CONTACT SEPARATOR-->
 <div class="sep contact" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></div>
 
 <div id="contactwrap">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <p>GET IN CONTACT</p>
     <p>Dont worry, that warm tingling in your fingers is only your animalistic urge to give us a shout! Feel free to hop onto our mailing list or just drop us a message - We would love to hear from you.</p>   
      <p><small><a href="http://www.google.com/">Twitter</a><br/>
      <a href="http://www.google.com/">Facebook</a></small></p>    
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <form action="http://weave.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a728b31e70e478151dac586df&amp;id=adea7a56c1" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
       <div class="form-group"></div>
         <label for="mce-NAME">Your Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="NAME" type="text" id="mce-NAME" placeholder="Enter Name" data-validate="validate(required, email)" required="required">
         <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="EMAIL" type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter Email" data-validate="validate(required, email)" required="required">
         <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Message</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3"></textarea>
       <br>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
   
   </div><!--/row-->
  </div><!--/container-->
 </div>
 
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>    
 <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
   $.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalOffset: 40
   });
  });
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        //    fancybox
          jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
      });
    </script>
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-65614881-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page is at www.weave.ws if that helps - honestly I'm really struggling with this one so thanks very much in advanced.

Cheers

Comment: Firstly, it's very difficult for anyone to answer this question because "renders incorrectly" offers no insight as to the issue. Is it JS related? CSS? images missing? Functionality not firing?

Anyhow, there may be an issue with JQuery not loading fast enough, as all other assets are running off `/assets/`. Add this line of code under your JQuery Definition (And obviously download a copy of JQuery and put it in the right path...)

`<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.10.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve it last night... after using the W3C code checkers and cleaning code and whatnot, the issue was fixed on the cross browser checks but still not on my local PC when run off the server - I than realized seeing as it was some social links and an email form perhaps it was being blocked by my AdBlock extension... and voila that was the cause!

@Pete - your point is also very good I will plan to implement that improvement as well later this week.

Thanks again everyone - Hopefully someone can use this to at least proof check that this isn't the cause if they have some slight issues in the future.

Cheers